# Will yield expression block if execute asynchronous operation?

Tags: javascript, generator, yield

I have learned that when we call `next()`, the code will continue to run until the yield keyword, and `next()` return will hold this value. My question is, if yield expression is doing an asynchronous operation, such as perform a file io or http request, and **before the asynchronous call is done**, we call `next`, is the code will still block, or resume running immediately even the asynchronous operation has not finished? And Why?

```
function * generator(){
  yield http.get('http://google.com');
  yield http.get('http://yahoo.com');
}
var gen = generator();
var a = gen.next();
var b = gen.next();
```

If google.com's request has not finished, will yahoo.com's request be sent immediately? or it has to block and wait for the google's request being finished?

Answer (score 0):

If the method "get" you are using is *anynchronous*, it will return immediately (non blocking) . This means that yahoo.com's request will be sent even if google.com is not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted will not wait for each `http.get` request to execute. It is however possible to do this by changing how the generator is used.

The following code shows how you could implement an asynchronous sleep function using callbacks and generators:

```
function wait(ms) {
    return function (cb) {
        setTimeout(cb, ms);
    };
}

function * generator(startTime) {
    console.log('start ' + (Date.now() - startTime));
    yield wait(1000);
    console.log('stop ' + (Date.now() - startTime));
}

console.log("Using generator asynchronously")
var gen2 = generator(Date.now());

gen2.next().value(function () {
    gen2.next();
});
```

It is however still possible to ignore the callback and make yield return immediately.

```
console.log("Using generator synchronously")
var gen1 = generator(Date.now());
gen1.next();
gen1.next();
```

For the code you posted it would make the most sense to have `http.get` return a `Promise`. In that case you could have code similar to this:

```
function * generator(){
    var google = yield http.get('http://google.com');
    var yahoo = yield http.get('http://yahoo.com');
}

var gen = generator();

loop(gen);

function loop(gen, next) {
    var result = gen.next(next);

    if (!result.done) {
        result.value.then(function (value) {
            loop(gen, value)
        });
    }
}
```